# Backbone.js - prevent PUT/POST on model.validate failure

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Using the following as an example:

```
var Case = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function(){

    this.bind("error", function(model, error){
        console.log(error)
      });
    },

  url: function() { 
    return '/api/kase?id=' + this.get("id"); 
  },

  validate: function(attrs) {

    return "An error";  



  }
});
```

In this case the validate method does not get called:

```
var kase = new Case();
kase.save();
```

In this case the validate method does not get called either:

```
var kase = new Case({subject: null});
kase.save();
```

In this case the validate method does get called, but the POST request is still made on save:

```
var kase = new Case();
kase.set("subject",null);
// An error
kase.save();
// POST http://localhost.local/api/kase?id=undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

Is this the expected behaviour?  Am I missing something with regard to 'cancelling' the POST/PUT request when client side validation fails?  Or should I be checking for a valid model before hitting the save method? (think the penny may have just dropped).

Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set that fails won't update the model data while a call to save without parameters will post/put the current state of the model to the server (empty in your case). On the other hand, if you call your save method with the data to be validated, it will stop if the validation fails:

```
 var kase = new Case();
 kase.save({subject:null});
```

should log an error and stop before posting to the server.

Comment: Many thanks nikoshr.  That was the explanation I was looking for. Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Do you have code elsewhere that is calling `save` on the model?

Backbone does not call the server when setting a model's attributes; even if the validation fails.

Comment: Apologies, I tried to simplify my problem using the above example - in hindsight, that was a mistake. I'll update the question with a more appropriate example. Thanks for the input.